# What does (void(^)(id) stand for in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm a newbie to Objective-C and see the method has an argument like

```
onArgument:(void(^)(id)) argument
```

Could you help me to explain `(void(^)(id))`

Comment: It's a block. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a code block. [check here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1)

Simply, it means you can write small code and pass it to that function. For example this is a simple block that logs object class:

```
void (^myBlock)(id) = ^(id) {
    NSLog(@"class: %@", [id class]);
};
```

The id in parenthesis means, your block would receive an id as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`void(^)(id)` is a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).  You can read all about it in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

a block of type VOID with one parameter of type ID